# Apache camel salesforce component - how to start multiple routes with their own connection parameters?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have multiple salesforce instances I would like to connect with using apache camel SalesforceComponent. The connection parameters (clientId, secret etc) are available only at runtime and different for each instance. How do I set this at runtime and create multiple instances of the route running in parallel?

I tried creating separate instances of the component, but that doesn't seem to be working.It always reads from application.properties

```
SalesforceComponent salesforce = new SalesforceComponent(camelContext);
salesforce.setLoginUrl("https://login.salesforce.com");
salesforce.setClientId("XXXXXXX");
salesforce.setRefreshToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
salesforce.setClientSecret("CCCCCCCCCCCC");
salesforce.setAuthenticationType(AuthenticationType.REFRESH_TOKEN);
```

I am using Spring Boot (2.7.2) and Camel (2.19.0)

(its similar to the issue - [Camel Salesforce - Multiple Components Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827458/camel-salesforce-multiple-components-configurations))

Adding more details:

Exception when setting the newly created with a different name (salesforcev2)

```
camelContext.addComponent("salesforcev2", component);
producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:my-route",
        "hello", String.class);

Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: salesforcev2://query?sObjectClass=com.salesforce.dto.QueryRecordsCase&sObjectQuery=SELECT+Id%2C+Subject+FROM+Case. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:579) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.client.AbstractClientBase.start(AbstractClientBase.java:91) ~[camel-salesforce-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
```

Route

```
       from("direct:my-route")
               .to("salesforcev2:query?sObjectQuery=SELECT Id, Subject FROM Case&sObjectClass=com.salesforce.dto.QueryRecordsCase")
            .streamCaching()
                    .to("log:my-log");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```java
SalesforceComponent salesforce2 = new SalesforceComponent();
// set component properties 
context.addComponent("salesforce2", salesforce2);
...
// in a RouteBuilder, etc.
from("salesforce2:query")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. I had tried this with different component name, but that was throwing null pointer while trying to get access token. I added the code and exception to my question above. The route is triggered manually. Please see above. Thanks

Comment: Session seems to be null when component is added with a different name.    And it fails in below line. 

public void start() throws Exception {
        this.accessToken = this.session.getAccessToken();

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Ross's answer above is correct. However, note that it works only in higher versions of camel. I upgraded to version 3.14.7 from 2.x that I was using. Unable to edit the above to add this.

```
    SalesforceComponent component = new SalesforceComponent();
    component.setClientId("xxxxxxxx");
    component.setClientSecret("xxxxxxxx");
    component.setRefreshToken("xxxxxxxx");
    component.setLoginUrl("https://login.salesforce.com");
    component.setAuthenticationType(AuthenticationType.REFRESH_TOKEN);
    component.setLazyLogin(false);

    // add it to context
    camelContext.addComponent("salesforcev2", component);
```